# Why am I getting 'Missing ; before statement' Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

First off, I'm really new to java, so I apologize if this is obvious.  Below is the first 6 lines of my script:

```
function myFunction (){

}import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
```

The erorr message I'm getting is this: **Missing ; before statement. (line 3)**.

If you need more of the script to make sense of the error, please let me know.

Comment: import... are java (not javascript) statements. You are mixing 2 different programming languages.

Comment: So I corrected my statement about javascript... but my question still stands... any takers?

Comment: Your question is nonsensical as you're asking about a javascript parsing error you receive when you put java code in the javascript editor.

Either change your question or update your code.  So far, what you're posting is not Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 1):

The import statements you are using are part of the Java programming language. Google Apps Script code is written in JavaScript, which has a similar name but is actually very different.  From JavaScript's [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript):

> JavaScript copies many names and naming conventions from Java, but the two languages are otherwise unrelated and have very different semantics.

If you want to learn how to program in JavaScript, [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're trying to program in java instead of javascript maybe ?